# Realign namespace definitions with file structure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, refactoring

Like all developers with OCD I try to organise my namespaces within our project so that they match where the file they are contained within sits of disk.

However after a pretty massive refactoring session within VS.NET I've moved files within projects and created new subfolders a plenty, leaving the refactoring of the namespaces to later believing that there must be a refactoring tool that will accomplish this for me once things have settled down. However I'm now not able to find such a tool!

Does anyone know of anyway to accomplish this automatically (ie. without me painstakingly going through 100s of files or even writing my own tool?).

Comment: I think namespaces are more analogous to folders than files.

Comment: Joel: Thats what I mean, is that not clear from my post? :(

Comment: Sounded like you often have entire namespaces all in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use the Class View window to rename the namespaces.
2. User "ReSharper" from jetbrains to do the refactoring.

Comment: (2) has kind of sailed now :) but I take your point about (1) that could well help to certain extent - still not quite as easy as I was hoping though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Refactor->Rename function on a namespace, just as you would on any other identifier.